# Bind values to multiselect using jsonresult in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have following ActionResult method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AssignViewers(long? where)
    {
        try
        {
            if (where == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Groups");
            }
            else
            {
                LoadGroups();
                ListViewers(where.ToString());

                return View();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**ListViewers** is a  JsonResult method,

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Listviewers(string where)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = new AssignUserViewModel();
            if (where != null)
            {
                long? groupid = Convert.ToInt64(where);

                AssignUserViewModel objassignuser = ..
                ...

                data = objassignuser;
            }                

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

So I'm trying to bind this **AssignUserViewModel** model properties on **AssignViewers** view intial loading and when its drop down values changing

```
@model Project.ViewModels.AssignUserViewModel
@{

}  

  <div class="col-lg-12">
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
           <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Group Name</label>
           <div class="col-md-11">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.groupID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Groups, "value", "name"), "Select the group", new { @class = "form-control" , id = "groupvalue"})
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Viewers</label>
          <div class="col-md-11">
          <select name="country" class="multi-select" multiple="" id="assign_item">
              @if (Model != null)
              {
                  var viewers = Model.Viewerlist;
                  foreach (var viewers in assignedviewers)
                  {
                    <option value="@viewers .UserId" selected>@viewers .UserFName @viewers .UserLName</option>

                 }
             }
                  </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
       multiselctpopulatefun();
      });

    $(function () {
        $('#groupvalue').change(function () {

            $("#assign_item option").remove();
            $("#assign_item").multiSelect('refresh');


            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Listviewers", "Groups")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { where: $('#groupvalue').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    multiselctpopulatefun();
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function multiselctpopulatefun() {
        $('#assign_item').multiSelect({
            ...
        });

    }
</script>
```

View

[image]

though values load in controller ,this is not binding model property values in view

Comment: Are you trying to implement cascading dropownlists?

Comment: @StephenMuecke just updated view

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to implement cascading dropdownlists (the code you have for the 2nd listbox will ever correctly bind to anything). You have not noted which jquery plugin your using, but just start by using the standard `@Html.ListBoxFor()` method without the plugin to get it working correctly.